# C# WPF program doesn't show in Windows 10 Search

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-search

I have created an msi installer with wix for a wpf program. But after installation my program doesn't show in the windows search. 
Do you need to create extra Registers to be sure your program will be indexed by the Windows Search Engine?

[image: this is the picture i get]

Comment: can you please share the path where you have installed your software?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram is the path were I installed my program

Comment: And I have a shortcut placed in the Menu Start Folder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyProgram"

Answer (score 0):

I have checked about you problem i am not much familiar with WIX but i have done some google for you.
Please check [Thislink](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html) i think you will find you solution here.

Comment: Yes I have done that,. What would you recommend instead of wix?

Comment: I am familiar with InstallShield. So i can only recommend that.